# Outer measure of symmetric difference zero implies measurable

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $E$ is a Lebesgue measurable set and let $F$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $$m^*(E\Delta F)=0$$
Show that $F$ is measurable.

I tried seeing [Prove that $\mu$(E$\Delta$F) = 0 implies $\mu$(E) = $\mu$(F)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1447319/prove-that-mue-deltaf-0-implies-mue-muf), however I believe I may not be able to use those results since outer measure is not finitely additive, while the measure is.

Next, I tried using the Caratheodory definition, i.e. showing for any set $A$, $m^*(A)\geq m^*(A\cap F)+m^*(A\cap F^c)$.

I managed to get till here:

$\begin{align}
m^*(A)&=m^*(A\cup(E\Delta F))\ \ \ \text{since}\ m^*(E\Delta F)=0\\
&\geq m^*((A\cup F)\cup (A\cap F^c))
\end{align}$

Just one more step from the conclusion... However I believe I can't say that $m^*((A\cup F)\cup (A\cap F^c))\geq m^*(A\cap F)+m^*(A\cup F^c)$, since outer measure is not finitely additive.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Simpler. What does it imply for $E\setminus F$, $F\setminus E$ and $E\cap F$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Hmm.. I know $m^*(E\setminus F)$ and $m^*(F\setminus E)$ are both zero. $m^*(E\cap F)=m^*(E\cup F)$. How do I proceed from there? Thanks!

Comment: What does $m^{\ast}(A) = 0$ tell you about $A$?

Comment: @DanielFischer If $m^*(A)=0$, then $A$ is measurable.

Comment: Ah-hah! And hence, $E\setminus (E\setminus F)$ …?

Comment: Hmm... $E\setminus (E\setminus F)=E\cap F$? Thanks for your patient help.. I think I am close to the solution but having a mental block

Comment: That, and it's the difference of two ??? sets.

Comment: @DanielFischer is the difference of two measurable sets measurable? I only learnt so far that the union of two measurable sets is measurable.

Comment: And intersection, I'm sure. And something else. And you know that $A\setminus B = A \cap \text{what?}$, probably.

Comment: @DanielFischer Eureka!! $E\cap F=E\setminus (E\setminus F)=E\cap (E\setminus F)^c$, thus $E\cap F$ is measurable as it is the intersection of two measurable sets. Thus $F$ is the union of $E\cap F$ and $F\setminus E$, two measurable sets and thus is measurable. Thanks for your guidance!